# Object creation is not working without using as a variable

Tags: php, class

This is working,

```
$classname = EventStatusType::EventRescheduled;
$eventStatus = new $classname;
```

But the following code throws Fatel Error,

```
$eventStatus = new EventStatusType::EventRescheduled;
```

What is the reason for this?

EventStatusType class is as follows

```
namespace Hello\App;

class EventStatusType
{
    const EventPostponed = \Hello\App\EventStatusType\EventPostponed::class;
    const EventRescheduled = \Hello\App\EventStatusType\EventRescheduled::class;
    const EventScheduled = \Hello\App\EventStatusType\EventScheduled::class;
    const EventCancelled = \Hello\App\EventStatusType\EventCancelled::class;
}
```

Comment: Because PHP syntax does not allow that? Imagine if you create class with constructor parameters `new EventStatusType::EventRescheduled('var1', 'var2')`

Comment: $eventStatus = (new ReflectionClass(EventStatusType::EventRescheduled))->newInstance();  Is it can do like this?

Comment: Yes, since in that form all variables are easily identified by parser

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck about one week due to this issue